# Error check if no user input in command line

Tags: c

My program takes a file name from the command line and then searches the file applying the median of medians algorithm.
I am trying to error check for no input/they press enter before typing anything. I have tried using strcmp to compare `argv` to `\n` with no luck as the program will not terminate if there is no value and you press enter.

Below is part of my `read_file` function:

```c
int* read_file(FILE*fp, char* file_name, int* arr_size){
   int *tempArray = NULL;  // init temp array to store converted values in
   scanf("%s\n", file_name); // scanf for user input filename
   
   if(strcmp(file_name, "\\n") == 0){
      exit(INCORRECT_NUMBER_OF_COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS);
   }
```

As well as part of `main` that takes `int argc` and `char*argv[]`:

```c
printf("Enter the name of a file w/ the extension: \n");

int* data1 = read_file(fp, argv[0], size); // read integers into array with the beginnging of file(x)
if (strcmp(argv[0], "\\n") == 0){
   exit(INCORRECT_NUMBER_OF_COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS);
}
printf("xth smallest: %d\n", xthSmallest(data1, 0, *size-1, data1[0]));  // print data
```

Note: the exit command is an enum in the header file

If I change the `read_file` parameter when I call the function in main, from `argv[0]` to `argv[1]`, the program seg faults as there is nothing being stored in `argv[1]` rather, the user input after running `./a.out` is stored in argv[0], NOT `a.out` in argv[0]

Comment: `strcmp(argv[0], "\\n")` is strange to compare against a 2 letter name.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've been trying some different things. Saw somewhere that to check a literal `\n` you needed to put another '\' before it.

Comment: Hint: `argc < 2`

Comment: PSA: `argv[0]` is not the first user argument. It's usually the name of the executable, as in `./a.out x` yields an `argv[0]` of `./a.out`. You probably mean `argv[1]`.

Comment: With `scanf("%s\n", file_name);`, that trailing `'\n'` is a problem.  Also, with `"%s"`, `file_name` will not contain white-spaces.

Comment: @tadman Oh right. Brain fart.

Comment: It's worth noting that `read_file` should focus on, as the name suggests, reading the file. It could handle a missing file error, but it shouldn't be dealing with "incorrect arguments". Attempt to open the file. If that fails, have a convention for returning an "invalid file" result, perhaps even just `NULL`. Do any argument screening external to that function, and within the function assume the arguments are at least *plausible* and worth using.

Comment: @tadman Right. I originally only had a file pointer == null check, but getting confused and desperate, added a check in there.

Comment: Remember there's a lot of fuss going on in the `errno` world you must pay attention to as well, so keep that in mind. Checking the result is `NULL` is very important, though. The next step is communicating to the user what went wrong, as in `errno` land there's a bunch of things that could have happened, from permissions, to file not being there, to something else.

Comment: @tadman I'm also still not understanding how I can check if enter has been pressed with no character inputs

Comment: Are you getting input from `argv` like you should be, or are you doing it via `scanf` or some other trick? You say "from command line" which means `argv[1]` as a start. Remember, if `argc >=2` then that value exists and it is, at the very least, a zero-length string. If someone's being dumb they could do `./a.out ""` but that's a *them* problem. Do what they ask.

Comment: @tadman in `read_file` I do a `scanf` and pass that to the main (call by reference)

Comment: @tadman OHHHHH Now I get it. Thank you for your time and help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to be checking in your

```
if (strcmp(argv[0], "\\n") == 0){
   exit(INCORRECT_NUMBER_OF_COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS);
}
```

block is something more like

```
if (argc < 2) {
   exit(INCORRECT_NUMBER_OF_COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS);
}
```

`argc` holds the number of arguments you get.  `argv` holds the arguments, where `argv[0]` is the name of the executable itself.

For example,

```
foo.exe bar baz biz
```

would be held as

```
argv[0] = "foo.exe"
argv[1] = "bar"
argv[2] = "baz"
argv[3] = "biz"
```

Which means `read_file(fp, argv[0], size)` should be `read_file(fp, argv[1], size)`.  You should also have it after your parameter check for safety.

Comment: `argv[4] == NULL`, which can be useful. `strcmp()` fails because neither argument may be `NULL`. (And `argv[N>argc]` is UB.)